# Extjs window close event

Tags: extjs4

I have a window with cancel button and the default close[x]. When the user clicks cancel button, it should check for a specific flag and the close the window and updates db. I am using me.close(this); for closing the window for cancel button. When the user clicks on [x], it should check for the same flag and updates db and then close the window. For checking that flag condition, I added a listener
This listener works fine. But after adding the listener, clicking the cancel button, the close event is called twice. So the db updation happens twice.
Could someone advice me how to handle the [x] close event for the window

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.updateForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    layout: {
        type: 'absolute'
    },
    title: 'Update Window',
    modal: true,
    initComponent: function() {

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id:'btnCancel',
                    handler    : function(){
                        if(flag == true){
                            //add to db
                            me.close(this);                                
                        }
                    }
                }]
        });    
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    listeners:{
        close:function(){
            if(flag == true){
                alert("close window");
                //add to db
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 10):

I have done this exact implementation with some minor differences and can attest that this works exactly as expected.

Here is my code:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
      ...
      buttons:[
            {
                text:'Finish',
                handler:function () {
                    this.up('window').close();
                }
            }
       ],
       listeners:{
            close:this.someFunction,
            scope:this
        }
      ....
```

This works perfectly. Which tells me that the issues is elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

One fix would be to simply call `close` when the `Cancel` button is pressed. I.e. do not perform the `(flag == true)` check when `Cancel` is pressed. This will not cause `close` to be called twice.

Comment: That is not possible as checking the condition and calling other function accordingly is must. Any other way we can handle this?

Comment: Hmm did you by any chance look into the Window's [`beforeclose`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-event-beforeclose) event? I think it provides the right place where to execute your condition and return `true` or `false` depending on whether you actually want to close the window or not.

Comment: Hi, I tried beforeclose. Even then when I click cancel, close is getting called twice. listeners:{
  beforeclose:function(){
  alert("before close");
   if(flag == true){
    alert("close window");
   }
  }
 }

Comment: You should have the `write to db` part in one place only; ideally if the window is closed only (i.e. if you're going to return true from `beforeclose`). Does your code have that structure?